# AFNetworking 2.0 + UIProgressView how to correctly display progress for an upload session

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, uiprogressview, nsurlsession

I'm using an AFHTTPSessionManager subclass to download and upload data through webservices. Everything seems to work fine except for the upoload progress view, I'm using UIProgressView+AFNetworking category.
Code is set like that:

```
 NSURLSessionTask * task = [[AFHTTPSharedClient sharedHTTPClient] addMediaWithURI:self.filePath success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, BOOL added) {
        if (added) {
            NSLog(@"Operation succ");
        }
        weakSelf.progressContainerView.hidden = YES;
    } orFailure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        weakSelf.progressContainerView.hidden = YES;
    }];
    self.progressContainerView.hidden = NO;
    [self.uploadProgressView setProgressWithUploadProgressOfTask:(NSURLSessionUploadTask*)task animated:YES];
```

This method directly calls:

```
session = [self POST:ApiPostURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mediaURI] name: ParameterMultimedia error:appendError];
        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
            if ([responseObject[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ko"]) {
                NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"it.share.auth" code:500 userInfo:nil];
                failure(task, error);
                return ;
            }
            success (task, YES);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            failure(task, error);
        }];
```

Once I attach the progress view if I check in its method I can se that is correctly observing the task progress in the method :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(__unused NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context <br>
```

The problem is that  `if ([object countOfBytesExpectedToSend] > 0)` is always false because `countOfBytesExpectedToSend` is 0, reading the doc about `NSURLSession` Apple says that:

> Discussion The URL loading system can determine the length of the
>   upload data in three ways:
>
> From the length of the NSData object provided as the upload body. From
>   the length of the file on disk provided as the upload body of an
>   upload task (not a download task). From the Content-Length in the
>   request object, if you explicitly set it

If I print the value from the request asking the header `Content-Leght` I get a valid value:

```
"Accept-Language" = "it;q=1, en;q=0.9, fr;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, ja;q=0.6, nl;q=0.5";
"Content-Length" = 232172;
"Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+357828FACC07BFAC";
"User-Agent" = "XXXXX/1.0 (iPad; iOS 7.1; Scale/1.00)";
```

I can't get why is always returning a value equal to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googleing, githubbing, I've found the answer, essentially this is a "feature" of NSURLSession, when you create a session with uploadstream the task takes over on your setted header. Since in a stream there is not a really content size, if we set something the task will rewrite it.

Fortunately NSURLSession has two request properties `currentRequest` (the overriden one) and the `originalRequest`. The original request will continue to keep our `Content-Length`. 
I made few mods to the UIProgressView+AFNetworking category to make it works using the set content length, it would be better another check to see if there is a stream.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(__unused NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 70000
    if (context == AFTaskCountOfBytesSentContext || context == AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesSent))]) {

            //upload content length issue
//            if ([object countOfBytesExpectedToSend] > 0) {
            NSInteger byteToSend = [[[object originalRequest] valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"] integerValue];
            if (byteToSend){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self setProgress:[object countOfBytesSent] / (byteToSend * 1.0f) animated:self.af_uploadProgressAnimated];
//                    [self setProgress:[object countOfBytesSent] / ([object countOfBytesExpectedToSend] * 1.0f) animated:self.af_uploadProgressAnimated];
                });
            }
        }

        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))]) {
            if ([object countOfBytesExpectedToReceive] > 0) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self setProgress:[object countOfBytesReceived] / ([object countOfBytesExpectedToReceive] * 1.0f) animated:self.af_downloadProgressAnimated];
                });
            }
        }

        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(state))]) {
            if ([(NSURLSessionTask *)object state] == NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted) {
                @try {
                    [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(state))];

                    if (context == AFTaskCountOfBytesSentContext) {
                        [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesSent))];
                    }

                    if (context == AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext) {
                        [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))];
                    }
                }
                @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {}
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: It works... but is not good change like that, you already report to @mattt? (AFNetworking)

Comment: I did as you can see here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1398 and https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1354 . Mattt has replied that he doesn't support this kind of mod.

Comment: And here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2027 . I totally understand Mattt point, because is a really untested mod in respect of all the test units of AFNetworking. I can tell you that I'm using it from about 6 month with success.